# FQL works on browser but doesnt work on Android

Tags: android, facebook-fql

I have this FQL Query, to get all my friends:

```
select name from user where uid in (select uid1 from friend where uid2=me())
```

This works fine on browser, passing the acess_token, but when try to use in Android, it doesnt work, it returne an empty jsonArray. This is the method:

```
String query = "select name from user where uid in (select uid1 from friend where uid2=me())";
        Bundle params = new Bundle();
        params.putString("q", query);
        params.putString("access_token", access_token);
        Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
        Request request = new Request(session,
            "/fql",                       
            params,                         
            HttpMethod.GET,                 
            new Request.Callback(){         
                public void onCompleted(Response response) {
                    JSONObject json;
                    json = new JSONObject();
                    json = response.getGraphObject().getInnerJSONObject();
                    Log.d("JSON_amigos", json.toString());
                }                  
        }); 
        Request.executeBatchAsync(request);
```

Comment: have you check Facebook 2.0?

Comment: i'm using Facebook SDK 3.0. What's on 2.0?